# Can I edit a LOOKUP column?

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, custom-list, updatelistitems

More concisely: How do I edit a lookup column?

> I have a custom list with columns [Name] and [Product] named
>   'MainList'. I would like a third column [Referral] which shows a name
>   found in custom list 'ReferralList'. Normally, I would just use a
>   Lookup column to ReferralList, but I want to be able to create new
>   item in ReferralList if not already there without leaving MainList
>   NewForm.aspx. Am I able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would be able to do this with a custom field type. You could either render a little button in there with JavaScript like "add new entry to list" which in turn only opens the newform of the ReferralList or create a totally new field type with a custom lookup.

YOu won't be able to do this out of the box.